# How do I get the file name when I select a file from <input type = "file">?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I wrote the code to create an  tag when I click the Add Attachment button.

And, I have the following code.

```
<input type="file" name="fileup['+idx+']" id="fileup['+idx+']">
<input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" value="fileSizeCheck" onclick="fileSizeCheck('+idx+')" />

function fileSizeCheck(idx)
{
    $('input[id="fileup['+idx+']"]').change(function()
    {
        var getName = $(this).val();
        console.log(getName);
    });
}
```

idx is a unique number that is generated each time a row is added, and it is an automatically incrementing value.

When I run the above code, I get the following result:

```
<input type="file" name="fileup[1]" id="fileup[1]">
<input type="file" name="fileup[2]" id="fileup[2]">
<input type="file" name="fileup[3]" id="fileup[3]">
<input type="file" name="fileup[4]" id="fileup[4]">
```

However, the contents of the script are not executed.
There is no indication in the alert window, nor is there confirmation from console.log.

That does not mean that page faults occur.

Did I make the grammar wrong?

I just want to get the filename when I select the file.

How do I write to implement what I want to implement?

Comment: Could you share rendered markup instead of markup from your code ?

Comment: hey change this `$('input[id="fileup['+idx+']"]').change(function()` into this `$('body').on('change', 'input[id="fileup['+idx+']"]', function(){...});`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9egsy4m7/

Comment: I'm afraid that OP has issue with newly generated rows on the page where events are not fired, and not the filename it self

Comment: What you are trying to change is function fileSizeCheck (idx) {Are you modifying the code here? } @KresimirPendic

Comment: @Rayon OK. I will try that

Comment: @KresimirPendic I solve that

Comment: did you just replaced that like I sent you?

Comment: No, I changed it as Rayon told me. @KresimirPendic

Comment: But I  don't know what the differences are.

Comment: What's the way you said, and what's the difference with my code? @KresimirPendic

Comment: great, gonna give @Rayon +1 to comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
function myfns() {

  input = document.getElementById('img');
 
  file = input.files[0];

  console.log(file.type)

  console.log(file.name)

  console.log(file.size)

 

}
```

```html
<input id="img" onchange="myfns()" type="file" name="imageUpload"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It became a reference.

Comment: @Seongwon-Choi Thanks for the comment